# TypeError: Numpy.float64 object is not callable iterating rows pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror, pandas-apply

Currently working on a dataset using pandas. Don't have much experience with this sort of stuff so any help would be greatly appreciated. dataset (shown below):

[image: sample dataset]

The table shows ratings associated with different segments grouped by year. I am attempting to parse the table and pull the most recent rating from its associated year column (excluding nans), and apply it to its respective place in the `Curr_Rate` column along with the year the rating was collected in the `Curr_RatingYr`.

The second task is to pull the second most recent rating (with respective year) and populate these values into the `Prev_Rate` and `PrevRatingYr` fields. Finally I need to generate averages from all the ratings available 2000-2017. I have the average part down, but when I try and parse the table to generate values for Current Rating and Previous Rating I am met with:

```
TypeError stating numpy.float64 object is not callable at index 0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
df = pd.read_excel('CurrPrevRate1.xlsx')

df.head()

dftest = df[:100]

    # Replace zeros with NaN
    dftest[['y2000', 'y2001', 'y2002', 'y2003', 'y2004', 'y2005', 'y2006','y2007', 'y2008', 'y2009', 'y2010', 'y2011', 'y2012', 'y2013', 'y2014', 'y2015', 'y2016', 'y2017']] = dftest[['y2000','y2001', 'y2002', 'y2003', 'y2004', 'y2005', 'y2006','y2007', 'y2008', 'y2009', 'y2010', 'y2011', 'y2012', 'y2013', 'y2014', 'y2015', 'y2016', 'y2017']].replace(0, np.nan)

    #Change all values in these columns to floats
    #dftest[['y2000', 'y2001', 'y2002', 'y2003', 'y2004', 'y2005', 'y2006','y2007', 'y2008', 'y2009', 'y2010', 'y2011', 'y2012', 'y2013', 'y2014', 'y2015', 'y2016', 'y2017']] = dftest[['y2000', 'y2001', 'y2002', 'y2003', 'y2004', 'y2005', 'y2006','y2007', 'y2008', 'y2009', 'y2010', 'y2011', 'y2012', 'y2013', 'y2014', 'y2015', 'y2016', 'y2017']].apply(pd.to_numeric)

    #Get average of rows 
    dftest['AvgRating'] = dftest[['y2000', 'y2001', 'y2002', 'y2003', 'y2004', 'y2005', 'y2006','y2007', 'y2008', 'y2009', 'y2010', 'y2011', 'y2012', 'y2013', 'y2014', 'y2015', 'y2016', 'y2017']].mean(axis=1)

    def getCurrRate():
        for x in dftest['y2017']:
            if 0 <= x <= 10:
                return x
            else:
                for y in dftest['y2016']:
                    if 0 <= y <= 10:
                        return y
                    else:
                        for z in dftest['y2015']:
                            if 0 <= z <= 10:
                                return z
                            else:
                                return 'N/A'

    dftest['Curr_Rate'] = dftest[['y2000', 'y2001', 'y2002', 'y2003', 'y2004', 'y2005', 'y2006','y2007', 'y2008', 'y2009', 'y2010', 'y2011', 'y2012', 'y2013', 'y2014', 'y2015', 'y2016', 'y2017']].apply(getCurrRate(), axis=1)

    dftest
```

Comment: Can you provide (a) actual, inline data instead of a screenshot, and (b) expected input and output?  More generally, you'll find you get better help, faster, when you post a [Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems related to your `apply()` syntax.

1. Call `apply()` with a function name, no `()` on the end.  E.g. `apply(getCurrRate, axis=1)`.
2. The function you apply your data to usually takes an argument, e.g. `getCurrRate(yr)`.  Here, `yr` is the object passed implicitly from `apply()`, so with `axis=1` you'd be executing:

   ```
   getCurrRate(dftest.y2000)
   getCurrRate(dftest.y2001)
   #...
   getCurrRate(dftest.y2017)
   ```

   But without a parameter in your `getCurrRate` definition, `apply()` doesn't have anything to apply on.

At least for the case of `currRate`, it seems like you really just want the most recent, non-`NaN` value from the `y<year>` columns.  In that case, consider a simpler approach:

```
def getCurrRate(yr):
    return yr.dropna()[-1]

ratings_cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('y')]
df['currRate'] = df[ratings_cols].apply(getCurrRate, axis=1)
```

Here's some toy data to demonstrate:

```
data = {'segmentId':['foo','bar','baz'],
        'y2015':[5, 6, 7],
        'y2016':[2, np.nan, 4],
        'y2017':[np.nan, np.nan, 9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
  segmentId  y2015  y2016  y2017
0       foo      5    2.0    NaN
1       bar      6    NaN    NaN
2       baz      7    4.0    9.0
```

We'd expect the following values for `currRate`:

- index `0`: 2
- index `1`: 6
- index `2`: 9

And that's what we get with the new `getCurrRate`:

```
df['currRate'] = df[ratings_cols].apply(getCurrRate, axis=1)

df
  segmentId  y2015  y2016  y2017  currRate
0       foo      5    2.0    NaN       2.0
1       bar      6    NaN    NaN       6.0
2       baz      7    4.0    9.0       9.0
```